# Get and Set condition value

Tags: c#, get, set, conditional-statements

I'm trying to learn get and set and I can't seem to figure out this problem. I have a condition to set a value, only set the value if it's greater than "_num = 10".

My problem is, even if the value is under 10 the value still sets. What am I missing? I should get an error with this code, but I'm not getting it...

thanks for ur time.

```
using System;

namespace Namespace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = Items.Sum = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class Items
    {
        private static int _num = 10;

        public static int Sum
        {
            get { return _num; }

            set
            {
                if (value > _num)
                    _num = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your have property as `static` and it will be set even before the constructor gets called. That’s why it is returning 10.

Please declare the main method as `public` not `private`.

Comment: i have tried and its still the same problem, i can still set "_num" less than 10 :(